# How to assign value to a BYTEA variable in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am kind of new to PostgreSQL and have been facing this issue when I tried to assign a value to BYTEA variable as below.

The below function input is a `BYTEA` value.

```
    DECLARE
       v_net bytea:= '0';
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE sample_pstgrs_func (v_net);


    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS Error_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
            RAISE NOTICE 'sample_pstgrs_func is Failure';
            RAISE NOTICE '% %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
            RAISE NOTICE 'Error Context : %', Error_context;
    END;
    $$   
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run this script,  I get the following error:

> ```
> NOTICE:  sample_pstgrs_func is Failure
> NOTICE:  42601 syntax error at or near "0"
> NOTICE:  Error Context : PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 15
> at EXECUTE
> ```

Please help as to how to assign a value in this scenario.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you need to use `perform`, not `execute`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks a lot , it works.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail, ideally with the code that throws the exception? It is fine to assign `'0'` to a `bytea`, that will result in one byte (hex 0x30).